# How do I show(not by alert but in the textarea itself) the value of the textarea after I apply a replace function when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script and html which are used in submitting a form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ApplyIndent() {
      var txtArea = document.getElementById('w2').value;
      var myRegExp = / /g;
      txtArea = txtArea.replace(myRegExp, "&#160;");
   }
</script>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td><textarea id="w2" cols="50" rows="5"/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td><input id="btnIndent" value="Indent" onclick="ApplyIndent()"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is to replace whitespace with non-breaking space because even if you indent lines of text in the text area, it just gets automatically justified after submitting the form unless you use non-breaking spaces.  I tested alerting the text area and I am getting my desired result, however, what I need is the value from the alert to get displayed on the text area itself.  How do I do it?  It's inefficient typing ascii characters just to get the desired space, we don't want that.  Thanks in advance!

[image: Using <space> to indent]

[image: Result when using <space> after submitting form]

[image: Using non-breaking space to indent]

[image: Result when using non-breaking space after submitting form]

Answer (score 1):

```
var txtArea = document.getElementById('w2');
txtArea.value = txtArea.value.replace(/ /, "&#160;");
```

Note that if you want the actual character represented by #160 instead of the HTML entity spelled out, use:

```
"\xA0"
```

EDIT: On second thought, what's wrong with the CSS `white-space: pre-wrap`?

Comment: I tried adding css white-space:

<style>
  #w2 {
     white-space: pre-wrap;
  } 
</style>

Still doesn't work.  I'm using Firefox 16.0.1 in Ubuntu 12.04
I'll try installing Google Chrome and see if it works.